# What is the common practice for white labeling a Django site?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-urls, white-labelling

I have a web application that I would like to allow white labeling for our clients. I have done this in PHP/ZendFramework, keying off the hostname (http://example.com), pulling the logo/colors/other from the database and rendering the main layout with those settings.

I am new to Python/Django1.5 and was wondering if anyone has implemented a white label feature into their application. How did you do it? Is there a common practice?

I have done some Googling and found an older blog implementing a white label feature using a url prefix, but I'm still running into some problems with rending the layouts

http://chase-seibert.github.com/blog/2011/08/05/django-white-label-styling-with-url-prefixes.html

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to basically do the same thing. Did you ever figure it out? If so, could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: I have submitted my answer and I hope its helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I really appreciate it and it confirms some of the things I was thinking.  If there is a better way, I would love for someone to post it, etc.  but, for now, I think I'm going with your solution.  :)  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I hope it works out!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did not find a good answer on this so i just implemented my own solution.

What I did was create a `Whitelabel` model that looked like this:

```
class Whitelabel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    primary_domain = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
```

Then I created a context processor in `application_name/context_processors.py` that checks the current host domain and sees if it matches any records `primary_domain` field. If there is a match, return the values for `name` and `logo` and assign them to the parameters `SITE_NAME` and `SITE_LOGO`. If no match is found, assign defualt values for `SITE_NAME` and `SITE_LOGO`, probably your default application name.

```
def whitelabel_processor(request):
    current_domain = request.get_host() 
    whitelabel = Whitelabel.objects.filter(primary_domain=current_domain).order_by('id')

    if whitelabel.count() != 0:
        config = {
            'SITE_NAME': whitelabel[0].name, 
            'SITE_LOGO': whitelabel[0].logo, 
            'SITE_DOMAIN': whitelabel[0].primary_domain
            }
    else:
        config = {
            'SITE_NAME': 'MY SITE', 
            'SITE_LOGO': '/static/images/logo.png', 
            'SITE_DOMAIN': 'http://%s' % Site.objects.get_current().domain
            }

    return config
```

Then I added the context processor to my settings file under `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    ...
    "context_processors.whitelabel_processor",
```

)

So that I can call them like so in my `base.html` template

```
<body>
    <h1>{{SITE_NAME}}</h1>
    <img src="{{SITE_LOGO}}" />
</body>
```

Here is some more documentation around template context processors.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors